# Queris related to "An arbitrary product $X=\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is connected iff $X_{\alpha }$ is connected for each $\alpha\in J$."

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness, open-map

> The following proof of
>
> ### An arbitrary product $X=\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is connected iff $X_{\alpha }$ is connected for each $\alpha\in J$   is provided by
>
> my  professor.I've some queries in this proof.

Let X is connected then we shall show that each $X_{\alpha}$ is connected,where $\alpha\in J,$some index set.

Consider $\pi_{\alpha}:X\rightarrow X_{\alpha},{\alpha}\in J$.

Since $\pi_{\alpha}$ is a projection map so it is continuous & $X$ is connected by assumption.

Using the result:"Continuous image of a connected set is connected."

we have $X_{\alpha}$ is connected.

### Conversely,

**Result Used**:

> X is connected iff every continuous function $f:X\rightarrow ${$0,1$}
> is constant.

Fix $f:X\rightarrow ${$0,1$} a continuous function.

Fix $(a_{\alpha})\in X$ and for each $\alpha\in J,$define $\varphi_{\alpha}:X_{\alpha}\rightarrow X$ by $\varphi_{\alpha}o\pi_{\beta}(x) =
\begin{cases}
a_{\beta},  & \text{if $\beta\neq \alpha$} \\[2ex]
x, & \text{if $\beta=\alpha$ }
\end{cases}$.

Let $g_{\alpha}=fo\varphi_{\alpha}:X_{\alpha}\rightarrow${$0,1$} for each $\alpha\in J.$Then each $g_{\alpha}$ is constant since $X$ is connected.

Hence,for each $\alpha\in J, f$ is constant on $\varphi [X_{\alpha}].$

Say,Without loss of generality,for some $\alpha_0\in J,f[\varphi_{\alpha_0[X_{\alpha}]}]=${$0$}.Since,$(a_{\alpha})\in \varphi_{\beta}[X_{\beta}]$ for each $\beta \in J,$ it must be that $\forall \alpha\in J,f[\varphi_{\alpha_0[X_{\alpha}]}]=${$0$}.

Then $f^{-1}$[{$0$}] is an open subset of $X$ by continuity which contains all of these elements.$\tag{*}$

### 1.(**Please clarify how $f^{-1}$[{$0$}] is open subset of $X$** :Is it because {0} is open in {0,1},$f$ is continuous,so inverse image of open set is open? )

Let $U\subset f^{-1}$[{$0$}] be a basis element of $X$ containing $(a_{\alpha})$ so that $\pi_{\alpha}[U]=X_{\alpha}$ for all but finitely many $\alpha \in J$.Let K be the finite subset of $J$ comprised of these $\alpha $ and let  $(x_{\alpha})\in U$ be that element such that $x_{\alpha}=a_{\alpha} $ if $\alpha \in K.$

Changing the coordinates of $(x_{\alpha})$ indexed by $K$ one at a time,it follows from ($*$) that each time we change it,it remains in $f^{-1}$[{$0$}].Since $\pi_{\alpha}[U]=X_{\alpha}$ for all but finitely many $\alpha \in J$.

We have shown that $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha=f^{-1}$[{$0$}].(##2.**I'm not getting this sudden transition.Please explain!!**)

If there is some scope of refinement in the above proof,feel free to express your views.Also check this proof critically...

Comment: In response to 1: yes

Comment: The definition of $\varphi$ is missing a subscript.

Comment: @William Elliot:see the edit

Comment: $\pi and \varphi$ appear to be in reverse order.

Comment: 2.  The leap of faith likely depends upon showing finite products of connected sets are connected.